# Location trigger is not fire in windows phone 8.1 Backgroundtask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, location, background-task

I am working with windows phone 8.1[RT] application for that I have update location in background , I am using `GeofenceMonitor` for that

```
 GeofenceMonitor gm = GeofenceMonitor.Current;
  gm.Geofences.Clear();
  Geoposition geoposition = await new Geolocator().GetGeopositionAsync();
  Geofence gf = new Geofence("InitalLocation", new Geocircle(geoposition.Coordinate.Point.Position, 1), MonitoredGeofenceStates.Entered | MonitoredGeofenceStates.Exited, false,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  gm.Geofences.Add(gf);
```

and add Backgroud task for Location Trigger

```
        var backgroundAccessStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        var geofenceTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
        {
            Name = "GeofenceBackgroundTask",
            TaskEntryPoint = "BackgroundTask.GeofenceBackgroundTask"
        };

        var trigger = new LocationTrigger(LocationTriggerType.Geofence);
        geofenceTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);
        var geofenceTask = geofenceTaskBuilder.Register();
```

I don't know where I am wrong but background task is not trigger , when my location in 1 m radios.

ref code found [here](https://github.com/jayway/GeofencingWP81)